# Next free value field

Tags: 7, entities

I need a custom field whose default value will be a "next free" value calculated using a user-defined scope (selection of content types). But before I even try to bother coding, maybe someone knows of such a contributed module? My searches returned nothing.

*I'd be reluctant to using Computed Field as I feel somewhat uncomfortable storing PHP code in database.*

Comment: Can you provide more information, with an example, about how the field would calculate it's value.

Comment: Let's say you have a product catalogue and you want to assign each new product with a unique UPC/EAN code - I'd expect Drupal to provide the nextfree value by looking through all used values and adding 1 to the max found value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could just use a [Serial field](http://drupal.org/project/serial)

> This module provides an auto-increment (serial) field.
>
> Unlike Drupal's built-in auto-increment node ID, which is global and
>   shared by nodes belonging to all content types, serial fields are
>   managed per content type (D6) / entity (D7). For example, the serial
>   field of an Invoice instance will generate a unique sequential number
>   (starting at 1, then 2, etc.) exclusively for Invoice instances.
>
> The allocation of serial numbers by this module is atomic. In other
>   words, the serial values are unique even when multiple instances of
>   the same content type / entity are created simultaneously.

Comment: That's a good base. Thanks. I just filed an issue at [Barcode](http://drupal.org/project/barcode) queue so that with additional alter hooks I could calculate the field using Serial.